Upgrading Kotlin Multi Platform local Realm app to cloud showing unresolved reference
I’m converting from a local Realm to one backed by MongoDB server. I follow the tutorial and all seems to go well but when I attempt to write the code to connect, I get an Unresolved Reference on MongoClient.create.
My code looks like this:
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient
import io.realm.kotlin.Realm
import io.realm.kotlin.RealmConfiguration
import io.realm.kotlin.ext.isManaged
import io.realm.kotlin.ext.query
import io.realm.kotlin.query.RealmResults
import org.mongodb.kbson.ObjectId
import todaysDateAsLong
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.w3c.dom.Document
import javax.management.Query.eq


fun connectToRealmServer()  {
// Replace the placeholders with your credentials and hostname
val uri = "mongodb+srv://MyCompany:<password>@atlascluster.j1c9yxd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=AtlasCluster"

val mongoClient = MongoClient.create(uri) //<-- UNRESEOLVED REFERENCE on .create
val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("sample_mflix")
val collection = database.getCollection<Document>("movies")
runBlocking {
    val doc = collection.find(eq("title", "Back to the Future")).firstOrNull()
    if (doc != null) {
        println(doc.toJson())
    } else {
        println("No matching documents found.")
    }
}
mongoClient.close()
}

My build.gradle looks like this (cut down to just the germane area)
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
id("io.realm.kotlin") version "1.11.1"
}

....

dependencies {
implementation(libs.androidx.material)
implementation(libs.androidx.material3.android)
implementation(libs.mongodb.driver.kotlin.coroutine)
implementation(libs.bson.kotlinx)
}

The relevant libs.version.toml entries look like this:
mongodb-driver-kotlin-coroutine = { module = "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-kotlin-coroutine", version = "5.1.0" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = 
"kotlin" }

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Are there things I need to remove going from a local Realm to the cloud that could be causing this?
The attached image shows some of the configurations within Android Studio in case they are helpful.


Couple of things:
I would advise reviewing the Getting Started documentation on adding Sync to your app as it’s pretty straightforward and well tested Add Device Sync to an App - Kotlin SDK
If you're using MongoClient.create (per the question) then it needs to be passed a MongoClientSettings object. That object should be instantiated with .builder with applyConnectionString. Some short code like this will do it
val mongoClient = MongoClient.create(
    MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyConnectionString(ConnectionString("<your connection string>"))
        .build()
)

The connection string would be in this format
"mongodb+srv:/<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>?connectTimeoutMS(2000)"

There are additional options on the ConnectionString class as well.
